# C++ namespace in a separate file used by others

Tags: c++, namespaces, include

I keep finding that I often want to have a set of "global" parameters for a program - variables used by many different classes in different files compiled separately.  I would like to keep these parameters together, concise and easily accessible, something like

```
namespace Params {
    static int WindowHeight = 600;
    //...etc.
};
```

However, if this is included to make a.o and b.o, "static" makes those variables local to each .o file rather than keeping them shared and ditching "static" leads to multiple definitions.
Another option would be to create a static class like

```
class Params {
  public:
    static int WindowHeight;
    //...etc.
}
```

But then you have to initialize the parameters separately elsewhere:

int Params::WindowHeight = 600;

and that is something I would really like to avoid.
I'll even accept something like the following (which didn't work for me, by the way)

```
namespace Params {
    static int WindowHeight
#ifdef __MUST_INIT_PARAMS
    = 600
#endif
    ;
};
```

as long as each entry can be kept to one place.

Any ideas?  Any kind of help would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: Static class members that are integral types (as in your example above) can be initialized inline. (e.g static int WindowHeight = 600; )

Comment: I think that is only true in some compilers because my gcc complains.    `error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘var’`  I guess it would have to be a const, but that won't work for me.

Comment: @StokedOver9k - He meant to say "static const class members that are integral types".

Comment: @Rob - You're correct of course.  Your telepathic abilities are amazing :-)

Answer (score 1):

If all of your parameters are integers known at compile time, you can use an `enum`:

```
namespace Params {
  enum e {
    WindowHeight = 600,
    // etc.
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
  InitWindow(Params::WindowHeight);
```

Comment: An yes... but some of the parameters might not be integers and some might change.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an `extern` instead of the `static`.
Define it once in a cpp file.

**//Filename.h**

```
namespace Params 
{
    extern int WindowHeight;
};
```

Define it One of the cpp files
**//Filename.cpp**

```
namespace Params 
{
    int WindowHeight = 100;
};
```

Comment: I still get multiple definitions during linking.

Comment: @StokedOver9k: It's hard to tell why unless you *show* what have you done.

Answer (score 0):

Your first use of `static` declares a variable that is specific to each translation unit that includes the header. Inside a class, `static` means a whole new thing - it declares a class-scoped variable.

To define globals inside of a namespace, you need to use `extern`:

```
//header.h
namespace Params {
    extern int WindowHeight;
};

//definition.cpp
namespace Params
{
    int WindowHeight = 600;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.
However, the whole idea here is to keep the params (definition and declaration) all in one place (one file).
Is that possible or is the only way to go, the standard .h + .cpp combo?  I am not too stoked on creating an extra .o (or having to write the default values into main).

Comment: @StokedOver9k a `#define WindowHeight 600` would do that, if you don't want to declare it `extern`. Not that you don't have to create an extra `.o`, you just need to define WindowHeight in a `cpp` file, doesn't matter which one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
//Params.h

namespace Params {
    extern int WindowHeight;  //it is declaration
};
```

and then in `.cpp` file:

```
//Params.cpp

 #include "Params.h" //not needed!

namespace Params {
    int WindowHeight = 600;  //it is definition
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, you need to use extern and not static. If you want the declaration and definition in the same file, your last attempt with the define will work if you use extern:

```
namespace Params {
    extern int WindowHeight
#ifdef __MUST_INIT_PARAMS
    = 600
#endif
    ;
};
```